# call function without object in c++

Tags: c++, function

I am new to c++ and have a trouble with functions that does not seems to be a bit unusual (or maybe I just do not know the right name). I have created a class vector that is supposed to work like the c++ vector, but is probably a bit simpler. I know that whenever possible you should use the already existent classes, but for the practice I want to create an own vector class.

So what I want to do is simply to create a function that can be called somehow "stand alone". Earlier I have managed to create a function scalar (calculates scalar product) that can be called like,

```
myVector v1(5);
myVector v2(5);

for(int i=0; i<5; i++){ //missing proper function here, this is not part of the question
    v1[i] = i;
    v2[i] = i+1;
}
double prod = v1.scalar(v1,v2);
//or better
double prod2 = v1.scalar(v2);
```

However what I really want to do is to create a function that does not need to operate on an object to work. I want to use the function something like

```
double prod3 = scalar(v1,v2);
```

is this possible and where should I define the function. I do want it to have the properties of an ordinary function rather than a inline function if possible. Also if this kind of functions have a name I would be happy to know.

/BR Patrik

Comment: A free function? It's the same idea, but outside of a class.

Comment: Is that the name? Thanks. where do you define it (except in main file)?

Comment: @patrik: The official name is "non-member function" or just "function". You can define them in any source file, outside any other class or function definitions, inside or outside a namespace. Your introductory book should cover function definitions in detail.

Comment: I guess you have a mistake in your code: you defined two *arrays* with 5 vectors each. I guess you wanted to define two vectors of size 5 each.

Comment: No not really, the [] is an overloaded operator to my custom class

Comment: I mean in your first lines: `myVector v1[5]` Here you define 5 objects of type `myVector` in an array. Maybe you mean `myVector v1(5)` similar to how you can initialize a `std::vector` with 5 elements.

Comment: Ah yes typo. Sorry I will edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could declare the function outside the vector class but in the same namespace/file and then define it accordingly.

For example:

```
namespace math {
    class Vector
    {
       ...
    }

    double scalar(const Vector& v1, const Vector& v2);
}
```

And then in the cpp:

```
namespace math {
    Vector::Vector()
    {
       ...
    }

    double scalar(const Vector& v1, const Vector& v2)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

You don't need to use namespace but it makes it cleaner in my opinion. Call would look like:

```
math::Vector v1;
math::Vector v2;

double prod = math::scalar(v1, v2);
```

As pointed out in the comments, you could also put the method as a static member of the class. It is also a way to avoid adding to the global namespace. You can do it like so:

```
class Vector
{
    static double scalar(const Vector& v1, const Vector& v2);
}
```

And then call it:

```
myVector v1;
myVector v2;

...

double prod = myVector::scalar(v1,v2);
```

Comment: Please add example of static function in a class, which is another possibility.

Comment: Ok thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for. If I would simply place the function in a header file instead, then the function would be compiled directly to the main file right? As if it was written there?

Comment: The syntax is then `myVector::scalar`, not `myVector.scalar`.

Comment: @leemes Thanks, damn copy paste ;)

Comment: And in your namespace version, you don't need to specify the namespace when calling `scalar` thanks to Koenig lookup aka ADL (argument dependent lookup). `double prod = scalar(v1, v2);` That's because C++ can derive the namespace by looking at the arguments you're trying to call the function with.

Comment: @patrik You will have multiply defined symbol if you define a a function in a header and include it in more than one translation unit.